# how can l prevent overlay of dynamic buttons when they are distributed randomly?

Tags: c#

l am trying to do a game and for that, l need to place buttons randomly without overlying on each other. When l run the code, buttons sometimes overly each other. l do not know how to prevent this. How can l prevent this?

here is my code:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
        int x, y,n,c= 0;
        private void beginnerToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
            List<int> mynumber = new List<int>() {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
            List<Color> mycolor = new List<Color>() { Color.AliceBlue, Color.AntiqueWhite, Color.Aqua, Color.Aquamarine, Color.Azure, Color.Beige, Color.Blue, Color.Brown, Color.Chocolate, Color.DarkOrange, Color.Red,Color.Red,Color.Yellow,Color.SpringGreen };
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {   
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Size = new Size(50, 50);
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    x = rnd.Next(0, 500);
                    y = rnd.Next(0, 430);
                    n = rnd.Next(0, 10);
                    c = rnd.Next(0, mycolor.Count);
                    btn.Location = new Point(x, y);
                    btn.Text = mynumber[n].ToString();
                    btn.BackColor = Color.Black;
                    btn.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 12,FontStyle.Bold);
                    btn.ForeColor = mycolor[c];
                    buttons.Add(btn);
                    pnlbtn.Controls.Add(btn);
                }




            }
```

Comment: You need to check if your randomly generated button position will overlap any of your previously generated buttons, before you add it to buttons/pnlBtn.Controls. If it does, you will need to re-calculate its position. You know your buttons size and you know your already generated buttons positions. The rest is a simple `if button.posX.Position in buttons[x].Position` check ...

Comment: l do not get how to do it via if function instead of foreach?

Comment: I would extract some of your code into a seperated `private Button GenerateRndButton()`-method. Inside that method, you generate your button. Your next method could be `private bool IsOverlapping(Button rndButton)`. here we check if `rndButton.Location` would be inside/ontop of any of your previously generated buttons (be aware, that you need to check for button.location + Size property - your `new Size(50, 50)`)

Comment: thank you very much for your help